What should we do about the tags "attack", "weaknesses", "vulnerability", "security", and "resilience"?
attack, resilience, weaknesses, security, and vulnerability all seem to be covering roughly the same topic.
Which should we keep, which should we merge, and why?

I agree that the current tags are confusing. I don't think we should just merge them though. It seems like there are a couple distinct categories represented.
We should have three tags, weaknesses, security, wallet-security. Questions with attack, resilience, and vulnerability should be retagged or closed:

weaknesses would cover problems with Bitcoin that are not security related.
Is Bitcoin inherently dependent on electricity?
security would cover problems with the Bitcoin (and altcoins!) client itself, and the Bitcoin protocol.
What can an attacker with 51% of hash power do?
wallet-security would cover how to keep your wallet secure (i.e. encryption)
How secure is an encrypted wallet?
Questions about how secure specific services are would be closed.
How is Coinbase any different than Mt Gox?
Some of those questions wouldn't have any of those tags.
Do any of the Bitcoin exchanges implement trading curbs?
What is the role of bitcoin wallets?

Thoughts?
Edit: It looks like nobody has any objections, so I'm going to go ahead and start retagging.
Still TODO:

Retag attack, ~65
Look at security questions, possibly retag, ~291
Look at weaknesses questions, possibly retag, ~30
Check security tag wiki
Check weaknesses tag wiki

DONE:

Retag resilience, ~2
Retag vulnerability, ~15
Synonym resilience -> weaknesses
Synonym vulnerability -> security
Check wallet-security tag wiki


Thanks. I like the idea for the distinction of weaknesses and security, although I am not sure they can always be clearly distinguished (which is not a problem though). I am not sure about "service-security" that seems to be scratching the topic of service reviews. So, what would you do with [tag:attack], [tag:resilience], and [tag:vulnerability] though?

@Murch I am not sure about "service-security" I'm not sure about that either. The other options would be to 1) ignore those questions, or 2) close them as off-topic. So, what would you do with attack, resilience, and vulnerability Merge them into one of the categories I mentioned. So the two resilience questions would go into [tag:weaknesses]

@Murch I've edited my post.

@Murch What should we do if we don't receive any more input?

The same thing we do every day: We do, what we think is best. ;)  If I understand that figure correctly, this question has  been seen by 28 people, so at least nobody disagreed vehemently enough to express disagreement. I think the latest version of your proposition would be a significant improvement to the current state, and I support running with it.

Apparently somebody already took care of the resilience tag wiki. I think blacklisting of tags can only be done by community managers, at least I couldn't find an option to do so anywhere. We could create a synonym so that it would automatically be changed to one of the remaining tags instead though.

What is the status of this endeavour? Do you need help, or is it finished? Is there anything left that we can automatically retag from one tag to another?
